# Google maps invalid key

Tags: google-maps

I have a google maps page uploaded to the following site: http://www.canning.co.nz/Mapping/directions.html

I have got an API key via the google site and have pasted it into the following line:

Is this the correct place to put it? I get an error saying that I need a new key, even though I got it from the Google Site.

thanks

Comment: You might also consider changing to the Google Maps API V3 since V2 is deprecated and could be shut off next year.

Answer (score 0):

1. your key appears quite short. Isn't it cut?
2. yes, this is the correct way to specify key to google maps api v2
3. make sure this key is not bound to some domain (you would have to enter the domain during the registration process).

Comment: (1): It's a new Console key. They are shorter than the old Version 2 keys.

Answer (score 0):

You also must activate the **Google Maps API v2**-service inside the [API-console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)

Answer (score 0):

In the allowed referers specify the following:

```
sitename.com
sitename.com/*
www.sitename.com
www.sitename.com/*
*.sitename.com
*.sitename.com/*
```

Where of course sitename is your interested domain :)